# how to get looped textbox values with comma seperated in jSON to insert into mysql database in jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

Thanks in advance. Actually I have a users combobox and below I have a courses textboxes and price textboxes which is coming from for loop. So I need to insert user's combobox value into mysql table " username " column, courses texboxes values with comma seperated into "course " column and prices textboxes values with comma seperated into "price" column. Something like this as below.

```
id | username | course            | price 
1  | Rakesh   |PMP,COBIT,CAPM     | 45,56,35
```

I have written a jquery code but i don't know how to combine all values and to pass in json format. Just i need to pass in jSON, other code to insert into mysql database is written in php.This php code i have written seperately.My code will show only jquery script as below.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
   die("Could not connect:".mysql_error());

}
mysql_select_db("cakephp",$con); 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from courses order by id desc");   

?>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">  
     .row_selected {background-color: #BFCBD7;} 
    </style>
  <script>


 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#btn').click(function(){

       var userVal = $('#users').val();
       alert(userVal);

       $('.courses').each(function(){
         var course = $(this).val();
         alert(course);
       });

       $('.prices').each(function(){
         var price = $(this).val();
         alert(price);
       });

       $.ajax({

            method: "POST",
            url: "/invl_exams/submitprice",
            cache: "false",            
            data: {examData: {username:userVal,courses:course,prices:price}},                            
            dataType: "text",   
            success: function(strMessage){  
            //alert(strMessage); 
            console.log(strMessage); 
             //$('#msg').html(strMessage);       

            },
            error: function(strMessage){
              //alert('error'); 
              console.log('error');           
            } 



       });

   });

 });


  </script>

</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="dynamicTextbox.php">     
   Users:<select name="users" id="users">
          <option value="">-- select --</option> 
          <option value="Ramesh">Ramesh</option>
          <option value="Suresh">Suresh</option>
          <option value="Girish">Girish</option>
        </select>   
   <table>    
   <?php

    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {     

   ?>

  <tr>
      <td><label for='Course'>Course&nbsp;</label><input type='text' class='courses' name='txtcourse' value =''></td>
       <td><label for='Price'>Price&nbsp;</label><input type='text' class='prices' name='txtprice' value =''></td>
    </tr>

   <?php
    }
   ?>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btn" value="Submit"></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually in my code i have alert all field data to check the values. Please tell me have you done any changes in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the values of `courses` and `prices` in JavaScript separated by `comma`.

```
var course_arr = [];
$('.courses').each(function(){
     course_arr.push($(this).val()); // Push all values in array
});

var course = course_arr.join(', '); // Concatenate array by comma separated string

var price_arr = [];
$('.prices').each(function(){
     price_arr.push($(this).val()); // Push all values in array
});

var price = price_arr.join(', '); // Concatenate array by comma separated string
```

Now, variables `course` and `price` contains values in comma separated string which you have passed in `AJAX`. These values can be retrieved at PHP side and inserted into DB. Sanitize your inputs before inserting into DB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: please tell me how to sanitize the inputs

Comment: Here is the link to sanitize inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php